# What next For the db episodes?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

As we r seeing dragonball super on air .Though its being viewed now , it seems gt series was the end to whole dragonball saga; is it true? .I gained this conclusion by watching the super saiyan 4 and also the leaving of goku in final episode of gt .Please can someone clarify if there is any other part after gt? (In continued format for gt story)

Answer (score 4):

> Please can someone clarify if there is any other part after gt? (In continued format for gt story)

There is a special that happens after Dragon Ball GT, *Dragon Ball GT: A Hero's Legacy*. This special was aired between the 41st and 42nd episode of Dragon Ball GT, but sequentially it takes place 100 years after the end of GT.

You can read more about this special on the [Dragonball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_GT:_A_Hero's_Legacy).

---

As for why you are seeing discrepancies in the story that you remember from Dragon Ball GT and Dragon Ball Super, that is because Dragon Ball GT is not considered canonical to the original series. It should be looked at as supplemental and can be viewed for enjoyment, but is not considered what actually happened in the Dragon Ball universe.